# Unable to write a squarefree algorithm

Tags: python

I'm trying to write a function that returns true, if an integer is [Square-Free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer) - this is what I've tried:

```
def squarefree(n):
    for i in range (2,n-1):
        if n%(i**2)==0:
            return False
        else:
            return True
```

> In mathematics, a square-free, or quadratfrei (from German language) integer, is an integer which is divisible by no other perfect square than 1. For example, 10 is square-free but 18 is not, as 18 is divisible by 9 = 32. The smallest positive square-free numbers are

Comment: Sooo what's the question? And your formatting is off.

Comment: What is you question?

Comment: what is square free?

Comment: is this code write

Comment: The code as it is now checks if `n` is divisible by 4. So, the question is if the number is divisible by a _square number_?

Answer (score 0):

The main problem here is your returning whenever your if statement fails. Move the return out of the for loop. Also a quick time save you only need to go up to the 4th root of n.

```
import math

def squarefree(n):
    for i in range (2,math.ceil(math.sqrt(math.sqrt(n)))):
        if n%(i**2)==0:
            return False
    return True
```

you could probably optimise more by only checking prime numbers up to the 4th root of n.